# How to get one query about sales set on default date?

Tags: oracle, date

I have two tables, T_TEST and T_DEFAULT_DATE. T_TEST contains date and amount, and T_DEFAULT_DATE contains just P_DATE. 
First table T_TEST:

```
DATE          AMOUNT
-------- ----------
01.01.99         77
16.02.99         59
01.01.00         12
15.01.00         32
01.02.00        144
15.02.00        320
16.02.00        521
01.03.00         98
15.03.00         76
16.03.00         33
01.01.01         65
15.01.01         78
01.02.01         95
15.02.01         39
16.02.01         97
02.02.02         63
07.03.02         75
```

And second table T_DEFAULT_DATE:

```
P_DATE
--------
16.02.01
```

What I want to get is two queries established in a single query :

```
1. what is the amount of sale achieved on the same day last year (- 12 mounths)
2. amount of sales for whole past year (based on table T_DEFAULT_DATE)
3. the amount (sum) for whole mounth (default mounth : 1.2. 2001 - 28.2.2001)
```

Expected output is :

```
P_SDLY  P_LY   P_MS
----------- 
521     1236    231
```

I tryed with add_months(t_default_date.p_date, -12) , but I didn't get expected result. Please help

Comment: @Aleksej, I'm sorry. Oracle, I work in SQL Developer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this, assuming that your fields are stored in `date`  columns.

```
    SQL> with t_test(date_, amount) as
  2  (
  3  select to_date('01.01.99', 'dd.mm.rr'),          77 from dual union all
  4  select to_date('16.02.99', 'dd.mm.rr'),          59 from dual union all
  5  select to_date('01.01.00', 'dd.mm.rr'),          12 from dual union all
  6  select to_date('15.01.00', 'dd.mm.rr'),          32 from dual union all
  7  select to_date('01.02.00', 'dd.mm.rr'),         144 from dual union all
  8  select to_date('15.02.00', 'dd.mm.rr'),         320 from dual union all
  9  select to_date('16.02.00', 'dd.mm.rr'),         521 from dual union all
 10  select to_date('01.03.00', 'dd.mm.rr'),          98 from dual union all
 11  select to_date('15.03.00', 'dd.mm.rr'),          76 from dual union all
 12  select to_date('16.03.00', 'dd.mm.rr'),          33 from dual union all
 13  select to_date('01.01.01', 'dd.mm.rr'),          65 from dual union all
 14  select to_date('15.01.01', 'dd.mm.rr'),          78 from dual union all
 15  select to_date('01.02.01', 'dd.mm.rr'),          95 from dual union all
 16  select to_date('15.02.01', 'dd.mm.rr'),          39 from dual union all
 17  select to_date('16.02.01', 'dd.mm.rr'),          97 from dual union all
 18  select to_date('02.02.02', 'dd.mm.rr'),          63 from dual union all
 19  select to_date('07.03.02', 'dd.mm.rr'),          75 from dual
 20  ),
 21  t_default_date(p_date) as
 22  (
 23  select to_date('16.02.01', 'dd.mm.rr') from dual
 24  )
 25  select sum(
 26              case
 27                      when date_ between add_months(trunc(p_date, 'yyyy'), -12)
 28                              and trunc(p_date, 'yyyy')-1
 29                      then amount
 30                      else 0
 31              end
 32             ) as year,
 33         sum( decode (date_, add_months(p_date, -12), amount, 0) ) as day,
 34         sum( case
 35                  when date_ between
 36                              trunc(p_date, 'MM') and
 37                              last_day(p_date)
 38                    then amount
 39                  else
 40                      0
 41              end
 42            ) as month
 43  from t_test
 44  inner join t_default_date on (date_ between add_months(trunc(p_date, 'yyyy'), -12) and last_day(p_date) );

      YEAR        DAY      MONTH
---------- ---------- ----------
      1236        521        231

SQL>
```

This makes use of `add_months` to get exactly "one year ago"; if you need "365 days ago" (think of leap years), consider using something like `date - 365`

Comment: Yes, but is possible to this 2 queries write in one common query?

Comment: Thank you very much @Aleksej !!! This is just the result I wanted to achive  :) Sorry if is not good time, but I have just one little sub-query, I need to get the amount (sum) for whole  mounth (default mounth  : 1.2. 2001 - 28.2.2001) in that query

Comment: Tried to add, with `last_day`,  to get the last day of a month, and `trunc(...'MM')`, to get the first one. I based on the month of the default date; if you need a different month, simply edit the `between` range

Comment: This query is almost good, the entire mounth amount result for default date (16.02.2001) should be " 231" becouse this is the sum of 97+39+95. This query returned 985

Comment: It actually gets the amount for february 2000, one year ago starting form default date; to get the month of default date, remove the `add_months` part

Comment: OK, you helped me a lot. Thanks @Aleksej .. Can you just edit your query,  I get some error, just to be sure if I get it. Thanks

Comment: sum( case 
                when datum between
                            trunc(to_date(p_datum), 'MONTH') and
                            last_day(p_datum) 
                  then iznos
                else
                    0
            end         
            ) as P_TM    .. I wrote this and the query return 0..

Comment: No, the result is still 0